# What is the meaning of this sign?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I am new for iphone developing. I get code from any where but i can nit understand what is use of this sign (=)which is shown in below image.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sign show that u can move row up and down for this in UItable Class u will get function
which is define below.

> // Override to support rearranging the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
//write your code
```

}

> // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 6):

It means that you can move the row up or down in the table.

If you want to respond to those actions, take a look at your [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941). The section on "Reordering Table Rows" is the relevant part.

Comment: which function or parameter used for that?